# Why isn't variable x referenced well?

Tags: clips, jess

In the following jess / clips code, variable x is not well referenced. Why?

```
(assert (item 2))
(assert (item 12))

(defrule ex1not
    (not (item ?x))
    (item ?y & (> ?x 10)) <- HERE I GET "No such variable x"
    =>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern matches in the absence of a fact `(item ?x)`, for any value of `?x`; it is true when there are no `(item)` facts at all. The second pattern would then try to compare that `?x` to 10. If we were somehow at the second pattern, then since `?x` didn't match anything, it has no value, so you can't compare it to anything.

If you edit your question to add what you're actually trying to express, in English, I can edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: I just needed to know why isn't x referenced well. Thanks.